# Issues using rsync to migrate files to new server

Tags: rsync

I am trying to copy a directory full of directories and small files to a new server for an app migration.  rsync is always my go to tool for this type of migration but this time it is not working as expected.

The directory has 174,412 files and is 136g in size.  Based on this I created a 256G disk for them on the new server.

The issue is when I rsync'd the files over to the new server the new partition ran out of space before all files were copied.

I did some tests with a bigger destination disk on my test machine and when it finishes the total size on the new disk is 272G

```
time sudo rsync -avh /mnt/dotcms/* /data2/
sent 291.61G bytes  received 2.85M bytes  51.75M bytes/sec
total size is 291.52G  speedup is 1.00

df -h /data2
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/data2vg-data2lv  425G  272G  154G  64% /data2
```

The source is on a NAS and the new target is a XFS file system so first I thought it may be a block size issue.  But then I used the cp command and it copied the exact same size.

```
time sudo cp -av /mnt/dotcms/* /data

df -h /data2
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/data2vg-data2lv  425G  136G  290G  32% /data2
```

Why is rsync increasing the space used?

Comment: Add option `--sparse`.

Comment: @Cyrus won't that just delay the problem? I'd guess`-H` is also needed. Tim, try `find /mnt/dotcms/. -type f -links +1 -ls` (GNU `cp -av` preserves hard links

Comment: @jhnc: To make it as correct as possible many options are still missing. See: [Which flags to use on rsync to achieve full replication?](https://superuser.com/q/1601965/340330)

Comment: @Cyrus definitely, but probably not the cause of this specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/asset-storage), dotcms makes use of hard links. So, you need to give rsync the `-H` option to preserve them. Note that GNU's `cp -av` preserves hard links so doesn't have this problem.

Other rsync options you should consider using include:

- `-H`, `--hard-links` : preserve hard links
- `-A`, `--acls`       : preserve ACLs (implies --perms)
- `-X`, `--xattrs`     : preserve extended attributes
- `-S`, `--sparse`     : turn sequences of nulls into sparse blocks
- `--delete`           : delete extraneous files from destination dirs

This assumes you are running as root and that the destination is supposed to have the same users/groups as the source. If the users and groups are not the same, then @Cyrus' [alternative commandline](https://superuser.com/a/1602023/990780) using `--numeric-id` may be more appropriate.

Comment: I tested with just --sparse and it didn't make a difference.  I will re-run the test with the additional -HAX options.  I normally use the --delete with additional runs when I'm doing delta and final syncs.  The copy takes a couple of hours so I will update later this evening.

Comment: Using the additional options above resolved the issue.

`time sudo rsync -avh --sparse --hard-links --acls --xattrs /mnt/dotcms/* /data2/`